# Does it matter which way named functions are declared?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see named functions exampled this way:

```
var clearClick = function() {
    // do something
}
```

...and then used for binding like so:

```
$("#clear").bind(click, clearClick);
```

...or with the "shorthand" methodology thus:

```
$("#clear").click(clearClick);
```

But why not use a more "normal" (similar to other programming languages) construct like this:

```
function clearClick() {
    // do something
}
```

It works the same, doesn't it? Is there any disadvantage to defining functions in this traditional way? Is the previous way just jQuerians flaunting their newfangledness?

Comment: This is JavaScript FYI, jQuery is simply a library built on top of that. Also, here is this exact question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname :D

Comment: Whoever edited it: "nonymous" means "named", as "anonymous" means "not named" (the "a" portion meaning "without," anonymous means without a name). IOW, they were not typos on my part.

Comment: Nobody ever says __nonymous__, ever.

Comment: @Zenith why, [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nonymous) of course!

Comment: The opposite of "anonymous" is "onymous", not "nonymous". And even then, it's not the right word here.

Comment: @Mathletics Ahh! So it *must* be a word ;D

Comment: Google the one with 0 vowels. It is mentioned in the 1st page of results ... one time. Not too common.

Comment: @BoltClock: Sounds kind of ominous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This works**  Function expression

```
var clearClick = function() {
    // do something
}

$("#clear").bind(click, clearClick);
```

---

**This does not work**  Function expression. The order matters here.

```
$("#clear").bind(click, clearClick);

var clearClick = function() {
    // do something
}
```

But when you declare your function using a `function declaration` the order does not matter. 
One more advantage of the below syntax is that the function name appears in debugger.

```
function clearClick() {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: some older browsers have bugs related to function declarations.

Comment: This doesn't properly explain why. Please see [JavaScript Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet#Hoisting)

Answer (score 1):

One reason you might want to do it is how this works:

```
var clearClick;
$("#clear").click(clearClick);

clearClick = function() {
    // do something
}

... lots of stuff in here ...

clearClick = function() {
    // do something different
}
```

Comment: That click handler still won't work no matter how many times you change it.

Comment: @Mathletics Feel free to suggest changes. Remember its just a scaffolding to highlight the way to define and redefine.